# Values shifting to end of line because of encoding

Tags: sql-server, ssis, export-to-csv

I'm trying to create a .CSV file from a sql statement, in ssis.  The dile includes names with special characters like Latin and German letters.
I'm using Unicode but there is one word in Arab who keeps skipping to the end of the line and not in the place it belongs. 
I tried replacing special characters with replace char(10), char(13) etc, But it didn't help.
I've also tried using UTF8 encoding but I still need to mark Unicode because of the other Latin letters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `UTF-8` encoding. Then make sure you are trying to store data to a `nvarchar` data type.